# In ggplot2 v0.9.1 how do I get a scale_y_log10 in power-of-10 notation?

Tags: r, ggplot2, notation

I have recently updated my ggplot2 distribution from an old one (can't remember the version) to v0.9.1. Before the update, when I used a scale_y_log10 all the values were in power-of-10 notation, which was really nice to look at, especially by using LaTeX labeling. Now I get everything in scientific notation, and I can't say I like it very much when looking at the plots. It's just a detail, but is there a way to revert to the power-of-10 notation?

Thanks

Comment: The answer is probably outlined in this transition guide (0.9.XX was a big rewrite): http://cloud.github.com/downloads/hadley/ggplot2/guide-col.pdf

Comment: Indeed it is, @Chase. I don't have time to write an actual answer, but the solution can be found on pages 34-35 I believe.

Comment: Thank you guys, now ... how do I assign the rep for the correct answer? :)

Comment: Write something up with a simple example, and award it to yourself!

Answer (score 2):

Simply copy pasted what was on [page 33-34 in the guide](http://cloud.github.com/downloads/hadley/ggplot2/guide-col.pdf) Chase linked to in the comments above.

```
# install.packages(c("scales", "ggplot2"), dependencies = TRUE)
require(ggplot2)

DF <- data.frame(x = rlnorm(1000, m = 10, sd = 5))
```

Power-of-10 notation

```
(q <- ggplot(DF, aes(x = log(x))) + geom_histogram())
```

[image: Power-of-10 notation]
Power-of-10 notation

```
require(scales)
q + scale_x_continuous(labels = math_format(e^.x)) + xlab("x")
```

[image: Power-of-10 notation]